# NullReferenceException, MVC(c#) / UnitTest / AccountController / HttpContext

Tags: c#, mvc, юнит-тесты

[image: Результат теста]Здравствуйте, кто может мне помочь с UnitTest-ами в C#, конкретно говоря в MVC, не понимаю Exception идет от того что моя написанная программа ( UnitTest )  не полная или от `HttpContext` (возвращает `null`). Тест написан для `AccountController`. Код запускаемого теста:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        AccountController controller = new AccountController();
        ActionResult result = controller.Index() as ActionResult;
    }
}
```

Получаемая детальная информация об ошибке:

> Test Name:    Index
>
> Result Message:    Test method
>
> UnitProject.UnitTest.Index threw exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

---

Тест нормально пройден, простой пример тестового кода, добавлено инициализация для HttpContext [image: тестовый код].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Так вопрос-то в чем, если тест пройден?

Comment: Иницализацию HttpContext, кусок этого кода (которая отмечена в картинке), нужна писать отделно например в смежный проект, или написонное правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо инициализировать `HttpContext.Current`, он у Вас не заполнен и от этого валится ошибка. Вот пример вспомогательных классов, которые помогут Вам заполнять `HttpContext.Current`, с использованием [Mock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq.Delegates):

```
public class MockHttpSession : HttpSessionStateBase
{
    Dictionary<string, object> m_SessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public override object this[string name]
    {
        get { return m_SessionStorage[name]; }
        set { m_SessionStorage[name] = value; }
    }

    public override void Abandon() { }
}

public class MockHelpers
{
    public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
        var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer(
            "id", 
            new SessionStateItemCollection(),
            new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 
            10, 
            true,
            HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
            SessionStateMode.InProc, 
            false);

        SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);
        return httpContext;
    }
}
```

А в юнит-тесте, перед тем, как создать эеземпляр контроллера и вызвать метод - Вам необходимо сделать следующее:

```
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var session = new MockHttpSession();

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Server).Returns(server.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Session).Returns(session);

HttpContext.Current = MockHelpers.FakeHttpContext();

var controller = new AccountController();
controller.ControllerContext = 
  new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
ActionResult result = controller.Index() as ActionResult;
```

Либо без использования `Mock` заполнять `HttpContext.Current`:

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", ""),
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
```

ну и добавить туда недостающее, если будет валиться ошибка, к примеру `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Полезные ссылки:

1. [HttpContext - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Свойство HttpContext.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Moq.Delegates](https://libraries.io/nuget/Moq.Delegates)

Comment: стоит добавить что за `Mock` используется

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @LilySargsyan, если мой ответ помог решить Вам Ваш вопрос - Вы можете отметить его, как верный. Либо опубликовать свой ответ.

Comment: Иницализацию HttpContext, кусок этого кода (которая отмечена в картинке), нужна писать отделно например в смежный проект, или написонное правильно, то есть в  классе UnitTest ?.

Comment: @LilySargsyan, не совсем понял, Вы спрашиваете или утверждаете? Для тестов советую вынести в отдельный метод и навесить на этот метод аттрибут [TestInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx)

Comment: @LilySargsyan, с таким аттрибутом метод будет запускаться первым, в него как правило выносят инициализацию объектов, репозиториев, классов, контекстов - в общем всего того, что необходимо проинициализировать перед запуском тестов в пределах Вашего тестового класса.

Comment: Спрашиваю, не знаю как правильно

Comment: @LilySargsyan, перейдите по ссылке на сайт MSDN, там есть описание и пример использования. Ссылка [TestInitializeAttribute - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx). Если это новый вопрос - задавайте его отдельно, не удобно отвечать на такие вопросы в комментариях.