# Метод, использующий HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты

Есть статический метод `GetFilename` в статическом классе `FileUpload`. Этот метод проверяет если ли файл с таким именем на сервере, и если есть - изменяет имя файла на уникальное:

```
public static class FileUpload
{
    public static string GetFilename(string filename)
    {
        string fn = GetTranslit(filename);
        int count = 1;
        while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Product_Images"), fn)))
        {
            fn = InsertIndexInFilename(fn, count);
            count++;
        }
        return fn;
    }

    public static string InsertIndexInFilename(string filename, int index)
    {
        ...
    }

    private static string GetTranslit(string text)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Для этого метода надо написать модульные тесты. Например:

```
[TestClass()]
public class FileUploadTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetFilename_Unique_Filename()
    {
        string filename = "unique.jpg";
        string actual = "unique.jpg";

        string expected = FileUpload.GetFilename(filename);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Во время выполнение теста происходит исключение `NullReferenceException` в строке `while()` из-за `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`.

Я только начинаю изучать тестирование и не знаю, нормально ли будет заменить `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Product_Images")` на путь к локальной директории в коде? Если так делать нельзя, то какие могут быть варианты?

Comment: А что если использовать вместо `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` вот это [`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath(v=vs.110).aspx) кажется должно будет помочь

Comment: Тест не проходит, тоже исключение в том же месте.

Comment: Наткнулся на `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` замену на большом SO. Можно как-то попробовать заполнить контекст, на подобии этого: [NullReferenceException, MVC(c#) / UnitTest / AccountController / HttpContext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554677/189339) ознакомьтесь с этим ответом

Comment: Я не придумал, как можно применить тот способ без использования контроллера